# How to concatenate a tensor WITHIN axis=1?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor of shape`(2,2,2,2)`:

```
tensor([[[[   5.,    5.],
          [   5.,    5.]],

         [[  10.,   10.],
          [  10.,   10.]]],


        [[[ 100.,  100.],
          [ 100.,  100.]],

         [[1000., 1000.],
          [1000., 1000.]]]], device='cuda:0')
```

I want to transform it such that the tensor along axis=1 are repeated 3 times. And after applying `.view(-1)` to that I get a 1D resultant tensor as:

```
tensor([   5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,   5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,   5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100., 100.,  100.,  100.,  100., 100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000.  1000., 1000., 1000., 1000. 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000. 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000.], device='cuda:0')
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`torch.repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.repeat_interleave) to Repeat elements of a tensor.

```py
t.repeat_interleave(repeats=3, dim=1).view(-1)
tensor([   5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,
           5.,    5.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,
          10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
         100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000.,
        1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final_features = feature_combined.view(1, -1, feature_combined.size(-1))
                                 .repeat(1, 1, 3).view(1, -1).squeeze(0)
```

I assume that your input tensor in the shape of `(2, 2, 2, 2)` is in `feature_combined`. The shape of the resulting `final_features` is `([48])` as you desired.

```
print(feature_combined)

>>tensor([   5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,    5.,
       5.,    5.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,
      10.,   10.,   10.,   10.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,
     100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000.,
    1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000., 1000.])
```

Comment: Actually i will not be having the earlier tensors(such as feature_1 and feature2 give here) in my work. I will only have the last tensor(feature_combined). Can you get the desired tensor using computations done on last tensor alone?